# Where to set the "STOCK_LEVEL" in BigCommerce Theme Files so < 400 shows "OUT OF STOCK"

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to get the products in BigCommerce with a stock level below 400 to show as "OUT OF STOCK"

I edited the file in /templates/components/products/card.html

every instance where it said "{{#if stock_level '<' 1}}" I changed it to "{{#if stock_level '<' 400}}"

But it didn't change the add to cart button to out of stock on items with a stock level less than 400.

Am I missing something here?

Thank You....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use this to show out of stock or not.

{{#if stock_level '<' 201}}
OUT OF STOCK 7
{{/if}}

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on what theme you are using, but most themes look for {{#if product.out_of_stock}} or {{#if product.can_purchase}} to determine whether or not to show the out of stock message. So you may need to alter one of these instead.

Comment: ok, I will look through the theme files again and look for that. Thank You...